# Is there a way to define reusable properties to n-hibernate mappings?

Tags: nhibernate, hibernate, nhibernate-mapping, orm, hibernate-mapping

I have a scenario that i want to add some standard properties to my entities. Meaning that i will have e.g. 1 int and 2 string properties applied to all relevant entities. I have over 100 mapping files and most but not all will be hosts to these new properties. In the classes its easy to define this; in the mappings however i've found no reference other than creating a utility or xslt and applying that ([How to define reusable <generator> elements in hibernate mapping](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1529961/how-to-define-reusable-generator-elements-in-hibernate-mapping)).

However i want to be able to add/modify/remove properties from this "standard" mapping.

thx for any replies

Edit1: an example of the mapping i want to add

```
<property name="TimeOfEdit" column="TimeOfEdit" type="DateTime" not-null="true"/>
<many-to-one name="EditedBy" column="FK_EditedBy" cascade="save-update" not-null="true" />
```

Edit2:
I removed the accepted solution because with NH 2.1.1 XML Entities are not working (NH-1236) and NH will throw a "DTD is prohibited in this XML document"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems that the only to do this, is to use Dynamic Mapping (http://ayende.com/Blog/archive/2008/05/01/Dynamic-Mapping-with-NHibernate.aspx)

as such since i've already defined an interface that my entities will use for the new properties (lets say IAuditable) its just a matter of running the appropriate code at the NH-session initialization

```
Configuration cfg = new Configuration() Mappings mappings = cfg.CreateMappings(); 
foreach (var persistentClass in mappings.Classes) 
{ 
   if (persistentClass.MappedClass is IAuditable)
   {
     ...
   }
}
```

and then

```
cfg.BuildSessionFactory();
```

to have it wired up and ready to be used
for about 85 classes the performance impact is negligible

Answer (score 1):

It depends on how these properties are implemented in your classes.

If they are all defined in a **base class or interface**, you could map them once in the base class or interface, and derive using `union-subclass`. There are some limitations. Read [this chapter in the NHibernate documentation](http://knol.google.com/k/fabio-maulo/nhibernate-chapter-8/1nr4enxv3dpeq/11#8%282E%291%282E%295%282E%29%28C2%29%28A0%29Table_per_concrete_class) about it.

If you decide to put them together into a class, you could map them as a **user type**. This will be similar to a component, but you could specify some things like type names, lengths and others in the user type. You still need to specify each column name.

There is another option: you could use **XML entities**. This is a rather primitive feature from XML which is supported by NHibernate. Read [this chapter in the NH reference documentation](http://knol.google.com/k/fabio-maulo/nhibernate-chapter-8/1nr4enxv3dpeq/11#8%282E%291%282E%296%282E%29%28C2%29%28A0%29Table_per_concrete_class%282C%29_using_implicit_polymorphism) where it is mentioned.

Comment: XML Entities seems the best solution but i don't understand this statement "The disadvantage of this approach is that NHibernate does not generate SQL UNIONs when performing polymorphic queries. "
Isn't the appropriate xml combined with the mapping before NH consumes the mapping?

Besides that, i'm having trouble creating it, i can't seem to find a working example of XML Entities usage.

Comment: Finally i did make it work with xml entities, however it is quite impossible to define <property>-ies with that. The defining xml may only have a single root node and as such only <component>-s are really viable. <union-subclass>-ing wasn't feasable, an <id> element is required for the class

Answer (score 0):

Creating a special code generator for your specific case is your only option.

Comment: do you mean a one-off script/utility that will manipulate the mappings i want and inject the elements?

Comment: I mean a utility that will take some kind of source for the information and creates the mapping files which hibernate expects. That can mean to read the existing mapping files and add/remove elements from them but I prefer a process where I have one source (for example, special comments in the source files) and which generates the whole output file. Otherwise, you'll have spurious errors if someone manipulates an output file in a way that confuses the code generator. He'll have the bug and you won't, things like that.

Answer (score 0):

Option 1:
-Define these 3 properties in a base class

-have your entities inherit from this base

-set up 'table per class hierarchy'

Option 2:

-Define these 3 properties as a component.

-You can have the mapping for these 3 properties in one file that is reused.

Comment: unfortunately the component solution requires an extra class which is not exactly what i want. The first option is viable however i want to avoid because the subclasses of the abstract class are be defined in the abstract class's mapping file, whereas i would prefer a solution where i go to A's class mapping file, and there define (in some way) that i want inherited/injected the abstract class's properties

Answer (score 0):

You might take a look at [fluentNHibernate](http://wiki.fluentnhibernate.org/Main_Page), It will simplify the mapping work for you. With With auto mapping you may only need an abstract base class to define these properties.

Comment: unfortunately the standard xml mappings have already been laid out.